# only select n number of matched lines from HTML file using bash

Tags: html, bash, sed

Using this command:

```
sed -n '/<article class.*article--nyheter/,/<\/article>/p' news2.html > onlyArticles.html
```

I get all these articles tags in my html document. They are about 50+ articles.

Sample input:

```
<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    ... variable number of lines of dat
</article>

<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    ... variable number of lines of dat
</article>

<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    ... variable number of lines of dat
</article>

<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    ... variable number of lines of dat
</article>
```

I just want x number of articles. Like just top 2 articles.

Output:

```
<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    ... variable number of lines of dat
</article>

<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    ... variable number of lines of dat
</article>
```

This is just an example. What I am trying to achieve is to select only (x) number of matching nodes.

Is there any way to do it? Cannot just use simple `head` or `tail` as I need to extract the matching elements not just some x amount of lines.

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: I cannot use any parser at the moment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmllint` + `xpath` can be used requesting tags by position

```
xmllint --html --recover --xpath '//article[position()<=2]' tmp.html 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Should probably add the `--html` option.

Comment: I get a lot of these errors HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' when I run the above commans

Comment: Added option suggested by @Shawn and `--recover` option that will try to overcome html inconsistencies.

Comment: The only issue is that encoding of text is wrong.

Comment: do you have a sample?

Comment: Source file has this Flere blir 100 år – Tordis (102) tror hun vet noe av oppskriften and output file has this Flere blir 100 &Atilde;&yen;r &acirc;&#128;&#147; Tordis (102) tror hun vet noe av oppskriften

Comment: Try `echo 'cat //article[position()<=2]' | xmllint --shell tmp.html 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/<article/{:a;p;n;/<\/article>/!ba;p;x;s/^/x/;/x{2}/{x;q};x}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and on extended regexp `-En`.

Match and print lines between `<article` and `<\article>` then increment a counter in the hold space and quit processing if the number of occurrences is completed.

Alternative:

```
cat <<\! | sed -Enf - file
/<article/{
:a
p
n
/<\/article>/!ba
p            
x
s/^/x/
/x{2}/{
x     
q     
}
x
}
!
```

Comment: I get this "/<article/{:a;p;n;/<\/a ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @mohsinali1317 are you using GNU sed and also enclosing the commands within single quotes?

Comment: No I am not using GNU sed.

Comment: are you sure that it has to be in this format?

Comment: I get this sed: -: No such file or directory